# Dynamically refreshing the ListView with changes done to database android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I am most concerned about Performance issue and don't want users to wait for progress.

I have a chatActivity, where i show a ListView.

Here i send a chatMessage

```
Chats chat = new Chats(chatBox.getText().toString(),Chats.TYPE_MINE, dt.format(now));
chat.personId = chatee.getMyId();
chat.isDelievered = Chats.DELIEVERED_NONE;
chats.add(chat);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Notice that Chat delievery is set to NONE Right now. So basically the message is being added to the Chat List even its not delivered yet.

Now on back thread here is what's happening
It takes few seconds to send message where i do this

```
  boolean bool = sendMessage(m);
  if (bool)
     chatee.isDelievered = Chats.DELIEVERED_DONE; (MESSAGE SENT)

  if (chatee.isDelievered == Chats.DELIEVERED_DONE)
  {
     app.mDbHelper.saveMessage(chatee); // SAVING TO DATABASE
     Intent i = new  Intent(Constants.REFRESH_NOTIF).putExtra("refresh",Constants.REFRESH_NOTIF);
     context.sendBroadcast(i);
  }
```

It will send a broadcast to the activity.

Now here is the problem.
Broadcast call this function

```
public void callUIMethodForRefresh(Intent intent) 
{
    String ref = intent.getStringExtra("refresh");
    if (ref == null)
    {

    }
    else if (ref.equals(Constants.REFRESH_NOTIF))
    {
    }
}
```

Here i am confused of how can I reset that previous Chat object added to my List. 
Points to be noted , i can be sending messages at a very fast speed and the refresh could be called for an old message whereas a new message is already typed.

- ONE way is i make a For loop and check for all the "ChatList" array for the message sent and then replace its delivery notice, but again this is very low performance incase i have 1000+ objects in the list.
- Is there any way, i can attach the sqlite database with my listView adapter that automatically detects the changes and reset the listView etc and etc?

What could be the best strategies here to avoid performance issues.

Comment: what are you trying to refresh, is it a Listview - in such cases ListAdapter has a method- notifyDataSetChanged() => http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged() which will be use to you

if its a normal textview and other elements, you have re fill or update the data on ui and reset the new values in Widgets(Textview or such)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking into [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) (specifically a CusorLoader). Combining these with a CursorAdapter, you can use the ContentProvider which inserts/deletes/updates your sqlite database and notifies your loader to reload it's dataset and update the CursorAdapter/ListView.

Comment: This is the right way to do event-data driven UI updates, Loaders are available in the support library if you need to support pre 3.0 devices